# Add new profile to outlook, using outlook anywhere

Tags: outlook-anywhere

Im trying to add a new profile to outlook via outlook anwyhere, this machine is not domain joined and is not on the LAN, i have done the following:-

exchange server name: webmail.domain.com
username: john smith
more settings > connection >exchange proxy settings
URL: https://webmail.domain.com
on fast and slow connect via http
authentication: Basic

I ok all that, then press check name, i get the password prompt for user/pass, put in correct details, then get the following error "The action cannot be completed. the connection to Microsoft Exchange is unavailable, Outlook must be on line or connected to complete this action"

Just to note: Outlook anywhere works fine with existing profiles, im just trying to add a new profile using anywhere on a none domain joined laptop.

Thanks

EDIT: test exchange connectivity

Attempting to ping RPC endpoint 6001 (Exchange Information Store) on server webmail.domain.com.
    The attempt to ping the endpoint failed.
     Tell me more about this issue and how to resolve it

```
Additional Details
The RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE error (0x6ba) was thrown by the RPC Runtime process.
```

looking at this, my cas server is not listening on port 6001, but my backend server is, is this correct?

Thanks

Comment: Out of pure curiosity, are you the system administrator, trying to do this for all your users in the aggregate?

Comment: Im the sysadmin, just testing a setup, its somethign im going to need to be able to do to two new remote users. Cheers

Comment: Is the Exchange server name actually webmail.domain.com? That seems unusual. Usually only the external URL is something like webmail.domain.com. The Exchange server name is usually something like cas1.myinternaldomain.local, etc. What's the AD FQDN of the Exchange server?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the internal server name for server name even though i was connecting externally. then the new profile went through ok.

thanks for the help!